# Laravel env file issue writable access

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am uploading a project from the installer and I am getting a problem
env to be  writable.

I did not understand what to do with my problem.

[env file showing error in Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rl4wj.png)

Comment: I don't understand your question, you should add more details, show the error text, etc.

Comment: env file is used for local development you should not upload it to the server. instead you should configure your config variables in files under the config folder.

Answer (score -1):

change your .env file permission to be writable.

Comment: how i can change this thats I am asking  ?